# Unable to populate Label for Accessor using xliff/properties file

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a requirement ,where in I want to populate the label for an accessor from resource bundle ,but its not populating with the value for the key provided in the label .

The portal bundle has following entry:

```
CUST_ADD=Customer Address
```

and I'm using the below piece of code in the pagedef.xml to render Customer Address on the UI

```
  <Accessors>
          <Item Value="custAddList"
                Label="#{adfBundle['PortalBundle']['CUST_ADD']}"/>
  </Accessors>
```

But it is giving following error on UI :

```
STRINGMANAGER: Key: '#{adfBundle['PortalBundle']['CUST_ADD']}' not found in bundle 'oracle.javatools.resourcebundle.ResourceBundleRT'
```

Can any one tell me how do we populate this label from resource bundle.

Thanks,
Garima

Comment: adfBundle is not populated inside pageDef, use it in jspx pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below command

## {adfBundle['CUST_ADD']}

adfBundle needs to be registered name in resource bundle

Answer (score 0):

I used : Label="#{adfBundle['portal.PortalBundle']['CUST_ADD']}"

we need to provide the absolute path of the portal bundle/properties file.